# Pagination issue in Angular 9

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have 3 blocks in a single page. I have implemented pagination on all 3 blocks.

Issue: When I try to navigate a to a different page in first block, like 3 in 1st block, 3 gets highlighted in all 3 blocks. irrespective of whether 3 is a valid number in 2nd and 3rd block. However, there is no change in the **data** that is displayed in each of the blocks.

I am using `ngFor` while implementing pagination.

Answer (score 1):

the problem would seem to be ngFor.
without code i can only guess what you did.
please post your code here so we can better understand what you did.
generally you shouldn't use nngFor for paging.
here is an example of use:

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {PageEvent} from '@angular/material/paginator';

/**
 * @title Configurable paginator
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'paginator-configurable-example',
  templateUrl: 'paginator-configurable-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['paginator-configurable-example.css'],
})
export class PaginatorConfigurableExample {
  // MatPaginator Inputs
  length = 100;
  pageSize = 10;
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 25, 100];

  // MatPaginator Output
  pageEvent: PageEvent;

  setPageSizeOptions(setPageSizeOptionsInput: string) {
    if (setPageSizeOptionsInput) {
      this.pageSizeOptions = setPageSizeOptionsInput.split(',').map(str => +str);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.mat-form-field {
  margin-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>List length</mat-label>
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="length" type="number">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Page size</mat-label>
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="pageSize" type="number">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Page size options</mat-label>
  <input matInput [ngModel]="pageSizeOptions" (ngModelChange)="setPageSizeOptions($event)"
         [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}" placeholder="Ex. 10,25,50">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-paginator [length]="length"
               [pageSize]="pageSize"
               [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
               (page)="pageEvent = $event">
</mat-paginator>

<div *ngIf="pageEvent">
  <h5>Page Change Event Properties</h5>
  <div>List length: {{pageEvent.length}}</div>
  <div>Page size: {{pageEvent.pageSize}}</div>
  <div>Page index: {{pageEvent.pageIndex}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have created separate html files for each block. Please find the code snippet of one of the block below:

<tr *ngFor="let jlist of tableData |filter:searchText| orderBy: order:reverse | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: active }; let i = index">

                <td>{{jlist.ID}}</td>

                <td>{{jlist.role.label}}</td>

                <td>{{jlist.managementLevelGroup.name}}</td>

                <td >{{jlist.AccountStatus}}</td>

</tr>

Comment: can you post also the TS file?